# Extjs 3.3.3 Grid - Disable grid rows

Tags: extjs, grid, gridpanel

My scenario is, i need to disable the extjs grid panel and enable the scroll bar even when the grid is disabled. I can disable the grid using 'disabled:true' of GridPanel, but this property disables the vertical scroll bar of grid also. Here i need vertical scroll bar to be enabled so that i can see all the elements in the grid.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
jai.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean disable the grid so that rows can't be selected or edited?  If so, the SelectionModel has a lock/unlock feature that may be what you are looking for.

Comment: i am aware of that, i need to mask the grid rows which implicitly says the user that he is not allowed to select rows. Is there any way to do so?